# Kivy Universal Background Image For Every Screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following python code:

```
kv = Builder.load_file("lordofthe90.kv")

class FirstMenu(Screen):
    pass

class SecondMenu(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Game(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

Game().run()
```

And the following kv code:

```
Manager:
    FirstMenu:
    SecondMenu:

<FirstMenu>
    name: "FirstMenu"
    Image:
        source: "background.png"
    *more stuff*

</FirstMenu>

<SecondMenu>
    name: "SecondMenu"
    Image:
        source: "background.png"
    *more stuff*

</SecondMenu>
```

I plan on having quite a few menus however the issue is, with all these menus, I would need to keep repeating "background".png. This is a background that goes under each widget in the current screen. Is there any way to declare this once without having to repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your `kv`:

```
<Screen>:
    Image:
        source: 'background.png'
```

This will add that `Image` to every `Screen`.